# Installing Vuforia for Augmented Reality apps

Tags: android, vuforia

I'm trying to install Vuforia so I can develop Augmented Reality apps for my phone. I'm on step 3: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-3-compiling-running-vuforia-sample-app

Here is the step I'm on:

```
Change directory to ImageTargets in the <DEVELOPMENT_ROOT>\vuforia-sdk-android-xx-yy-zz\samples
```

where xx-yy-zz is the version number. (mine is 2-6-10)

My problem is that I don't have anything called ImageTargets and no files in my samples folder.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually download them and add them to the samples folder. You have the choice to download all of the samples or you can download individual samples, e.g. ImageTargets.

Find the samples for all platforms (including Android) here: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps

Answer (score 0):

Try Downloading the Vuforia package for unity again and include it in your project. May be your package got corrupted while downloading...